# css inline-block div positioning

Tags: positioning, css

I'm trying to fix a positing issue in a responsive design.

I have a container div, containing 4 (but it could be more or less) divs that are displayed as inline-block. I would like to know how to control the number of divs per line when the page is resized (with CSS, if it's possible). For example, when 4 containees no longer fits in the container, the last one is moved to second line. I would like in that case to have 2 containees in the first line and 2 containees in the second line. I dont know how to do that. Your help would be welcomed!

EDIT:
it could also be 6 containees, in the case the layout would be:
- 1 line of 6 blocks if it fits
- 2 lines of 3 blocks
- 3 lines of 2 blocks
- 6 lines of one

the number of containees is variable. I just want to have the same number of containees per line

the html:

```
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="containee"></div>
   <div class="containee"></div>
   <div class="containee"></div>
   <div class="containee"></div>
</div>
```

the css:

```
.containee {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:tomato
}
```

the example can be seen here : http://cssdesk.com/uGLbq

(PS : I tried to find the solution searching the web but I dont really know the good keywords related with this topic)

Comment: What about grouping? http://cssdesk.com/eS7CR

Comment: If you have the right break point in your media query, you can make the margin of the second element bigger so it will force the other two elements to fall to the second line together.

Comment: grouping does not make the trick : if there is 6 elements, the layouts I want are 
- 6 on 1 line (if it fits)
- 3 per lines for 2 lines
- 2 per lines for 3 lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't with CSS (AFAIK).

You can do "the math" dynamically with Javascript in real time.

In your case,

- you known the width of one block (in *that* moment),
- you can easily get the window width (in *that* moment),
- you know the number of your block (in *that* moment);

Simply apply ( (1) the first time you open the page, and (2) every time the number of blocks changes, or (3) the resolution changes) the algorithm in the following code:

```
// EXAMPLE OF INPUT
var windowWidth    = 1400;  // read it...
var blockWidth     = 200;   // read it or use const...
var numberOfBlocks = 10;    // read it... 


// Calculate the maximum number of blocks per row
var maxBlocksPerRow;
for (var i=0; i < numberOfBlocks; i++) {
   if ( (blockWidth * (i + 1)) > windowWidth){
      maxBlocksPerRow = i;
      break; 
   }
}

// Check the highest 0 module combination while iterating backwards
var magicNumberForMatchingBlocks = 1; // if not found, it will be 1.
for (var i = maxBlocksPerRow; i > 0 ; i--) {
   if ( (numberOfBlocks % i) == 0){
      magicNumberForMatchingBlocks = i;
      break;
   }
}

alert("With " + numberOfBlocks + " blocks, each one wide " + 
      blockWidth + " pixels, and a window wide " + windowWidth + " pixels, 
      the number of blocks per row for having always 
      the same number of block in any row is: " + magicNumberForMatchingBlocks);
```

Then use that number to populate or re-arrange the elements with Javascript or better with some Javascript library like jQuery.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I'm disappointed I cant do that with CSS, but I'll do the trick with Javascript and jQuery. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grouped">
        <div class="containee"></div>
        <div class="containee"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grouped">
        <div class="containee"></div>
        <div class="containee"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.containee {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:tomato
}
.grouped {
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of containees is not fixed, it can be one or ten. I just want to display the same number of elements per line when there is not enought space to display them on one line. Moreover, I want to fit the maximum number of elements on one line. If there is enought space for 4 on one line, no need to have two lines

Comment: Ahh, I see. I don't think you can do what you want with css alone... Happy to be proved wrong of course! :)

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks MatW

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.container
{
  min-width: 410px;
}
```

Comment: that will fix the layout (I dont want to) and dont avoid to have 3 blocks on 1st line and 1 on 2nd

Comment: Oh, you changed your requirements.

Comment: Well actually that's what I mean from the beginning but I fear that my english is not very good. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Give the `.containee` a `float:left;` if the page fits for 4, they will be positioned right beside each other, else, you'll have another line of divs. You can give it as well a `margin-top:5px;` in case you got another line, the divs of the second line won't be glued to the divs of the first line. Note that with this approach, its not obliged to have equal number of `.containee` in each line, if you have 4, then you re-size, you'll have 3 - 1, then 2 - 2...etc..

Comment: I want to have the same number of containees per line. Actually, it's exactly want I'm looking for. Thanks for your help